# VSTS Build Triggers - Path Filters

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to setup some VSTS CI Builds and have a different build based on the Branch path.  We are using VSTS with GIT and I have setup the Branch Filters as follows:

- Exclude - refs/heads/ft1/nodeploy/*
- Include - refs/heads/ft1/*
- ... Repeated for each of the Feature Teams ...

However if I name the branch as FT1/blah it is not being picked up because the filter is case sensitive.  I am unable to find any documentation around the "Patterns" that are supported and I would rather not have to add the following:

- Exclude - refs/heads/FT1/nodeploy/*
- Exclude - refs/heads/Ft1/nodeploy/*
- Exclude - refs/heads/ft1/nodeploy/*
- Exclude - refs/heads/fT1/nodeploy/*
- Include - refs/heads/FT1/*
- Include - refs/heads/Ft1/*
- Include - refs/heads/ft1/*
- Include - refs/heads/fT1/*

as that would be so much more difficult to manage.  Does anyone else have any input on a better way to handle this?

Comment: Can't you just pick a case? Generally accepted practice for Git is lower case.

Comment: @MrHinsh that is one thing we discussed but when working across 3 locations (2 US and 1 India) it is easier to say than it is to do when working on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to do this.

Accepted practice is to choose a case and notify all engineered of the choice.

Answer (score 0):

For now, VSTS can’t support the branch filter like `refs/heads/*1/*` to match all the branches:

```
tf1/*
fT1/*
Ft1/*
FT1/*
```

I post a user voice about this function, you can vote up [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18471433-more-flexible-wildcard-used-in-branch-filter-trig).